# DAX Contains Function doesn't works with DirectQuery in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have been trying for some time to find a DAX formula to count a number of elements in a table with a search or string content condition. I tried this formula:

```
test_yes_answer = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(answers),answers[question_label]="Are you ok ?"
&&CONTAINSSTRING(answers[answer], "Yes"))
```

But the following error then returned to me when I displayed the result in a value field...
`local evaluation of Table.Join or Table.nestedJoin with key equality comparators is not supported`
Has anyone had this problem before or have any idea how to resolve/workaround this problem?

If I want to do this formula it is because my data looks like "Yes || I'm ok!" and I just wish I had the number of yes.

FYI, I use directQuery which also reduces the use of PowerQuery which could have allowed me to separate the fields.

Thanks in advance :D

As said above, I tried PowerQuery but the separation of fields does not work alongside DirectQuery, I also tried the "Search()" function or creating a new column in which we place a value according to the element to then sum the numbers in this new column, that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you simplify with a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to illustrate with minimal information what you're trying to do?

Comment: @pgSystemTester
In my application, users can check a checkbox (Yes or No) and add a comment, the result look likes : 
`
| id_user | label_question | answer |
|--|--|--|
| 1 | Are you ok ? | Yes || I'm very happy ! |
| 2 | Are you ok ? | Yes || Ok |
| 3 | Are you ok ? | No || vibes |
`
My objectiv in PowerBi is to Sum the answer where there is "Yes".
But this must adapt to different responses (around fifty different responses depending on usage, my application being professional, I do not have the right to share the data with you, I am sharing an example of how it works)

Comment: So... no, you won't use a markdown table, got it. I'm sure your writing makes sense to you, and if I was really interested, I'd try to decipher it, but markdown is just easier. Until you take that step, I suspect people we just glaze over your question as too wordy... especially as Dax isn't really an SO high interest. Good luck though.

Comment: Can you expand on your last paragraph "or creating a new column in which we place a value according to the element to then sum the numbers in this new column, that didn't work either." Created a new column where/how? Why didn't it work? What's the data source?